# what is throughput obtained by Load balancing

Tags: performance, tomcat, internal-load-balancer

i have performed a load test on a clustered environment having 2 tomcats and a Load Balancer, which was configured to distribute the load in the ration 1:1.
i got the throughput as 150/sec on jmeter which was sending the request on Load Balancer.

Now i want to know what does this throughput mean?

is it 75/sec from each tomcats or it is (150/sec+150/sec)/2.

please help me in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be the total requests at 150/sec - on average 75/sec for each tomcat.